# Google map api v3 not loading

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am upgrading google maps api from v2 to v3. for some reason, my map will not load. I followed the code outlines via the api and some other locations.

here is my code: am i placing the vars correctly? any help? the map can be found at [Casadragones](http://dev.casdragones.com)

```
var marker;
function load() {

  //get $result from browserdetect.php
    //if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    // *** if (is_browser_compatible()){ ***
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    //geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,         
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.513799, -35.375977),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    panControl: true;
    zoomControl: true; 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    mapobj = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); 
    /*
    mapobj = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
    mapobj.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());
    mapobj.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    //mapobj.setCenter(new GLatLng(28.728149, -88.992889),3); // old
    mapobj.setCenter(new GLatLng(40.513799, -35.375977), 2); // center in Atlantic in order to show US and UK        
    */
         // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      /*GDownloadUrl("<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php", function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);*/
      downloadUrl("<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php", function(data) {
      var xml = parseXml(data);
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
        var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
        var zipcode = markers[i].getAttribute("zipcode");
        var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
        var pairing = markers[i].getAttribute("pairing");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        //var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        //                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        marker = createMarker(point, name, address, city, state, zipcode, phone, type);
        marker.setMap(mapobj); 
        //mapobj.addOverlay(marker);
      }
    });
  //}
}
```

dom events and everything else are elsewhere. i think this is the code that has the most trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map isn't loading because none of your code is running. Look closely at these lines:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,         
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.513799, -35.375977),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    panControl: true;
    zoomControl: true; 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

Do you see the problem? If not, open the Developer Tools in Chrome, or similar developer tools in any browser, and load your page. You should get an error message pointing to the problem.

Not an error per se, but there should also be a `;` after the closing `}` in this object.

In addition, you're missing `var` declarations on some of your variables: `mapobj` and `geocoder` for example. Also, the `var marker` doesn't belong outside this function; move it inside.

What editor do you use to edit your code? I recommend editors that have live syntax checking, such as [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide), or [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). When I pasted your code into Komodo IDE, it immediately put squiggly red underlines on the syntax errors.

Comment: I use Notepad++. Thank you for the help. I do see the problem! var mabobj and geocoder are declared above this section outside of the function. should they also go inside? I will download Komodo IDE asap